# How can I refer to the schema I was trying to save in nestjs/mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to encrypt some passwords and get its salt before saving my model to mongoose in Nestjs, but simply using `this` to refer to the schema itself doesn't yield any results as it refers to the `UserSchemaProvider` object itself, instead of the current model I'm trying to save.

**My schema provider:**

```js
export const UserSchemaProvider = {
  name: 'User',
  useFactory: (): mongoose.Model<User> => {

      const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          name: { type: String, required: true },
          email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
          password: { type: String, required: true },
          birthday: { type: Date, required: true },
          celphoneNumber: String,
          whatsapp: Boolean,
          promo: Object,
          status: String
      });

      UserSchema.pre<User>('save', async (next) => {
          const user = this;
          console.log(user);
          if (user.password) {
              const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
              bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                  if (err) return next(err);

                  user.password = hash;
                  next();
              });
          }
      });

      return UserSchema;
  },
};
```

and my user `Module` comes below:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
      MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
          UserSchemaProvider]),
      HttpModule
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, Validator, ValidationPipe, IsEmailInUseConstraint, GoogleRecaptchaV3Constraint],
})
```

:Nest Platform Information:

platform-express version: **6.10.14**

mongoose version: **6.3.1**

common version: **6.10.14**

core version: **6.10.14**

Answer (score 3):

Your `pre` hook handler shouldn't be an `arrow function () => {}`. `mongoose` handler will need to have the execution context to point to a current `document` being saved. When using `arrow function`, your execution context of the `pre` hook is no longer the document, hence, `this` inside of the handler isn't the document itself anymore.

```js
export const UserSchemaProvider = {
  name: 'User',
  useFactory: (): mongoose.Model<User> => {

      const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          name: { type: String, required: true },
          email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
          password: { type: String, required: true },
          birthday: { type: Date, required: true },
          celphoneNumber: String,
          whatsapp: Boolean,
          promo: Object,
          status: String
      });

      UserSchema.pre<User>('save', async function(next) { // <-- change to a function instead
          const user = this;
          console.log(user);
          if (user.password) {
              const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
              bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                  if (err) return next(err);

                  user.password = hash;
                  next();
              });
          }
      });

      return UserSchema;
  },
};
```

Comment: That really made total difference, thanks, but after implementing that change, the function doesn't work. I will report this bug in nestjs git, thanks for you assistance.

Comment: Do you get any error? What’s the operation you’re actually using? is it “save”?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors, and as you mentioned, I'm using 'save' operation. The data simple flows to my mongodb server without password being hashed and the salt being saved.

Comment: I see your issue in NestJS repo. Just a heads up, you’ll probably be asked to provide a repro. I’m going to investigate this further myself. Have you tried creating your Schema outside of the Module decorator and just use the Schema like: MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: ‘User’, schema: UserSchema}])

Comment: Yes, I tried that too using ForFeatureAsync and declaring my factory in the module itself.

Comment: Thank you! I was facing the same issue. Changing the arrow function to a normal function helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I automatically changed the function to arrow function without realising it will cause issues.